# I want my app to look the same on every phone in Android Studio

Tags: android, layout, size

I designed an app with dp unit. I also used RelativeLayout. I designed app while Pixel 3XL screen selected [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fp1xq.png). After i finished the design i changed the screen to the Pixel [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPFpb.png). Now my design looks bigger.[Look the red line. Not equal to the Pixel 3XL.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhP1b.png) I want my app to look the same on every phone. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From Document:

> Android devices come in all shapes and sizes, so your app's layout
> needs to be flexible. That is, instead of defining your layout with
> rigid dimensions that assume a certain screen size and aspect ratio,
> your layout should gracefully respond to different screen sizes and
> orientations. By supporting as many screens as possible, your app can
> be made available to the greatest number of users with different
> devices, using a single APK. Additionally, making your app flexible
> for different screen sizes ensures that your app can handle window
> configuration changes on the device, such as when the user enables
> multi-window mode.
>
> This page shows you how to support different screen sizes with the
> following techniques:
>
> Use view dimensions that allow the layout to resize Create alternative
> UI layouts according to the screen configuration Provide bitmaps that
> can stretch with the views

https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

https://material.io/design/layout/responsive-layout-grid.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using constraintLayout if you want to build responsive designs.I have tested it on multiple devices and google also recommends it.Go through the link.

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

Comment: i tried to use with Constraintlayout and also i used Linear Layout, Relative Layout... But it's the same. Can i design only 5 inches? In other words, I want to design one by one.